# How to get image from the web and save it to a imageField using the url

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a image from the web and save it to the imageField using the images url.

The below code spits out a error ('JpegImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed').

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import io

if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)

    URL = 'http://www.image.jpg'

    with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
        file = io.BytesIO(url.read())

    img = Image.open(file)

    instance.image = img
```

Answer (score 0):

instance.image has to be of type `django.core.files.images.ImageFile` I am testing my models with this code. Maybe it points you to the correct direction :

```
# This gets me a temp Image for testing. In your case it would be a real file
def get_test_image_file(tmpdir=None):

    file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png', dir=tmpdir)
    return ImageFile(file, name=file.name)
```

and the for the model test I do :

```
def test_addimage_create(self):
    adimage = AdImage.objects.create(advertiser=self.advertiser,
                                     picture=get_test_image_file(tmpdir=MEDIA_ROOT))
    self.assertIsInstance(adimage, AdImage)
```

so in your case instead of `instance.image = img`. `img` has to be an Object of Type `ImageFile` which then can be assigned to the form.instance. Btw. you should assign the values to the instance before save()